# PHP JSON array_push replacing NULLS with blanks?

Tags: php, json

Hi guys I am using the array_Push function and I am wondering if there's any way for the array_push function to return

```
                array_push($result, array('order_id' => $row[0],
                                  'type'  => $row[2],
                                  'description' => nl2br($row[3]),
                                  'amount' => $row[4],
                                  ));
```

and with the json_encode i get

```
   "result":[{"order_id":"67","type":"HEADER","description":"Coca Cola","amount":null},{"order_id":"72","type":"TEXT","description":"French Fries","amount":null}
```

this is output in a table as

```
    $.each(data.result, function(){
        $("tbody").append("<tr id='order_"+this['order_id']+"'><td>"+this['type']+"</td><td></td><td>"+this['description']+" </td><td>"+this['amount']+"</td><br>");
```

So i was wondering if there is a way for the NULL values to be returned as blanks instead? IF so, where can I do this?

Comment: "Blanks" is not a thing in PHP, or any language I'm aware of for that matter.

Comment: You might want to fix the problem at the source. Do you really need / want `NULL` values in your table instead of empty strings for strings and a 0 for amounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
'amount' => (is_null($row[4]) ? '' : $row[4])
```

Comment: I'd use `=== null`, but that's just me. The fewer parenthesis the better. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($row as &$value){   
    $value = $value === null ? '' : $value;
}
```